# .plot_wireframes(x,y,z) causing errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm following a tutorial on how to do 3d Plot graphs in Python and it works fine up until the second last line

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as pt
fig = pt.figure()
chart = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection = "3d")
X,Y,Z = [3,15,23],[7,9,23],[7,10,19]
chart.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)
pt.show()
```

it keeps shooting out this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~~~\3D Plot.py", line 6, in <module>
    chart.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)
  File "~~~\Python3.11.1\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 1731, in plot_wireframe
    if Z.ndim != 2:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

/~~~ is just me censoring my file layout

I think it might be an out of date package but I don't know how to check/update for it. It also mentions ndim which every google search brings me to numpy, which I tried importing but to no success.

When I remove the second last line the code runs and shows an empty graph so I know it's the second last line breaking something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues: `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are Python lists, not NumPy arrays; `Z` is one-dimensional. The `plot_wireframe` method expects NumPy arrays as inputs, which have the `ndim` attribute. To fix the issues, you can convert the lists to NumPy arrays and make `Z` two-dimensional:

```
X, Y, Z = [3, 15, 23], [7, 9, 23], [[7, 10, 19],[7, 10, 19]]
X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)
Z = np.array(Z)

chart.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
```

Comment: that didn't seem to fix the issue :/ I'm now getting this as an error:
raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.")
ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.

Comment: Z has to be two dimensional. See a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225830/axes3d-plot-wireframex-y-z-error